# Proxy Configuration for Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, google

While trying to change the proxy settings for Google Chrome from Advanced Settings on Ubuntu 16.10, I am getting the following error:

> When running Google Chrome under a supported desktop environment, the system proxy settings will be used. However, either your system is not supported or there was a problem launching your system configuration.
>
> But you can still configure via the command line. Please see `man chrome` for more information on flags and environment variables.
>
> Well my friend using Ubuntu 16.04 is able to do it from the Chrome UI itself.

Comment: This is  a question directly related to Chrome and not the entirety of Ubuntu.  I'd argue it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Proxy settings for all applications

To access system-wide proxy settings, open the System Settings application from the dash, go to Network settings, and then go to Network proxy on the left.

### Proxy settings for just Chrome

If you want to set proxy options for just Chrome (and not system-wide), the only way I've seen to do that in Ubuntu is by using a Chrome extension. One that I've used for a while is [Proxy SwitchyOmega](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/padekgcemlokbadohgkifijomclgjgif), which features:

- Support for HTTP, HTTPS, and SOCKS 4 and 5 proxies
- With the Quick Switch option, one-click switching between the proxy and a direct connection or between multiple proxies
- A list of domain names that should automatically skip the proxy and use a direct connection instead
- Optional Chrome Sync support so that Chrome on your other computers (or new computers in the future) can automatically get the same Proxy SwitchyOmega settings